# Excel macro to insert carriage return

Tags: vba, excel, carriage-return

In my research, I've encountered two possibilities for inserting a carriage return into a header in a VBA macro, using Chr(10) or Chr(13).  I've even seen code posted by Allen Wyatt at [excel.tips.com](https://excel.tips.net/T001992_Multiple_Line_Headers_and_Footers.html) that seems to do exactly what I'm attempting, but where he asserts it works, I have yet to see success.

Here is the basic code I am attempting to execute:

```
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .CenterHeader = "&F" & Chr(10) & "&A"
End With
```

There is other formatting I'm doing, but it all succeeds.  This line only produces the filename in the header ("&F"), but no return and no tab name on the second line.  It also doesn't fail; it just continues right through this line.

This macro was originally recorded by me in Excel 2010, which I then augmented with additional automation for page formatting.  I'm still running it under Excel 2010, and it has never worked correctly on this particular line.  Does anyone have knowledge of what might be transpiring here?

Edit: Here is the full code from the original macro recording and my edits.

```
Application.PrintCommunication = False
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .PrintTitleRows = ""
    .PrintTitleColumns = ""
End With
Application.PrintCommunication = True
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
Application.PrintCommunication = False
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .PrintTitleRows = "$1:$1"
    .PrintTitleColumns = ""
    .LeftHeader = ""
    .CenterHeader = "&F" & vbCrLf & "&A"
    .RightHeader = ""
    .LeftFooter = ""
    .CenterFooter = ""
    .RightFooter = "Printed &D"
    .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.7)
    .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.7)
    .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
    .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
    .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
    .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
    .PrintHeadings = False
    .PrintGridlines = True
    .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
    .PrintQuality = 600
    .CenterHorizontally = False
    .CenterVertically = False
    .Orientation = xlPortrait
    .Draft = False
    .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
    .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
    .Order = xlDownThenOver
    .BlackAndWhite = False
    .Zoom = 100
    .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
    .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
    .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
    .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
    .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True
    .EvenPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
End With
Application.PrintCommunication = True
```

Comment: works for me, are you sure you do not have something in the code that limits the size of the header so it does not show the second line?

Comment: I would use `"&F" & vbCrLf & "&A"`

Comment: I changed to vbCrLf,.  Now the carriage return appears, but the tab name doesn't.  I'm not aware of anything specifically limiting the header size, but I'll comb through it and see.

Comment: I didn't see anything, but I'll post the code here if someone want to take a look.  I don't deny that this code change works (which I'll check the answer for), but it still isn't completing the entire line, which stymies me.

Comment: I thought I would follow up on this.  I discovered that both methods worked if I removed some of the additional lines of code that weren't actually doing anything (they were simply there from the macro when it was first recorded).  Once I eliminated things like the margin settings and empty header/footer lines, the carriage return and second line worked fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Agree with Patrick H.  This code works ...

```
Sub header()
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .CenterHeader = "&F" & vbCrLf & "&A"
End With
End Sub
```